# Parsing xfs_quota -c 'free' output with bash

Tags: xfs

Is it possible to parse the output of `xfs_quota -c "free" /mnt/xfs` in a deterministic way? The problem is that depending on the length of the path to the block device mounted on `/mnt/xfs` its output will be differently formatted.

With a block device with sufficiently short block device path `xfs_quota` will output on a single line:

```
└$ xfs_quota -c "free" /mnt/xfs
Filesystem           1K-blocks       Used  Available  Use% Pathname
/dev/loop20             983040     289076     693964   29% /mnt/xfs
```

But if the block device has a long path, for example if it is part of a LVM volume, the output will be split over multiple lines:

```
$ xfs_quota -c "free" /scratch/local
Filesystem           1K-blocks       Used  Available  Use% Pathname
/dev/mapper/vg_scratch-lv_scratch
                       1230848      32996    1197852    3% /scratch/local
```

`Xfs_quota` has a flag `-N` to hide headers, presumably to ease machine readability; but using it does not remove this variable behaviour.

```
$ xfs_quota -c "free -N" /scratch/local
/dev/mapper/vg_scratch-lv_scratch
                       1230848      32996    1197852    3% /scratch/local
```